# Auto table in jsPDF

Tags: angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

How to create a black border for table in plain theme in PDF generated from jsPDF?
I have tried writing in styles like

```
styles: {
   overflow: 'linebreak',
   border: 'solid black 1px'
}
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.It can be given by line width and line color.

`var doc = new jspdf('p','pt','a4');

       doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {
         headerStyles: {
        lineWidth: 0.06,
        lineColor: [217, 216, 216]
    },
       beforePageContent: header,
        margin: {top: 40},
        theme: 'plain',
        styles: {
                overflow: 'linebreak',
                lineWidth: 0.02,
                lineColor: [217, 216, 216]
              }
       });
        var header = function (data) {
          doc.setFontSize(25);
          doc.setTextColor(0);
          doc.text(this.companyname,15,15);
          doc.setFontStyle('normal');
        };
        doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(columns, rows);
        doc.save("file.pdf");`